# How can a Pinoccio lead scout make a POST request to a remote server?

Tags: arduino, pinocc.io

I'd like my [Pinocc.io](https://pinocc.io/) lead scout to make a POST request (e.g. to inform a remote service of an event that has been triggered).

Note that I don't want to listen to a constant stream the results (as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23556846/203371)) as I don't want to be constantly connected to the HQ (I'm going to enable the wi-fi connection only when required to minimize battery usage), and the events I'm detecting are infrequent.

I would have thought that this is a very common use case, yet I can find no examples of the lead scout POSTing any messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same message directly on the [Pinoccio website](https://pinocc.io/forum#!/getting-started:how-can-a-lead-scout-make-a) and I got this answer from an Admin

> Out of the gate, that's not supported via HQ. Mainly because to get as
> real-time performance between API/HQ and a Lead Scout, it makes most
> sense to leave a TCP socket open continually, and transfer data that
> way. HTTP, as you know, requires a connection, setup, transfer, and
> teardown upon each request.
>
> However, doesn't mean you can't get it
> working. In fact, you can do both if you wanted—leave the main TCP
> socket connected to HQ, and have a separate TCP client socket connect
> to any site/server you want and send whatever you like. It will
> require a custom Bootstrap, but you can then [expose any aspect of that
> functionality to HQ/ScoutScript directly](http://support.pinocc.io/hc/en-us/articles/200675735-Write-a-Custom-ScoutScript-Function).
>
> If you take a look at this [code](https://github.com/Pinoccio/library-pinoccio/blob/master/src/backpacks/wifi/WiFiBackpack.h#L55), that's the client object you'd use to open an HTTP connection.

So in a nutshell the lead scout cannot make a POST request. To do so you'll need to create a custom bootstrap (e.g. using the Arduino IDE).